# Calling operator new at global scope

Tags: c++, new-operator

A colleague and I were arguing the compilability of writing this at global scope:

```
int* g_pMyInt = new int;
```

My arguments revolved around the fact that calling a function (which `new` is)
at global scope was impossible. To my surprise, the above line compiled just fine
(MS-VC8 & Apple's LLVM 3).

So I went on and tried:

```
int* foo()
{
    return new int;
}
int* g_pMyInt = foo(); // Still global scope.
```

And, that compiled as well and worked like a charm (tested later with a class
whos constructor/destructor printed out a message. The ctor's message
went through, the dtor's didn't. Less surprised that time.)

While this appears very wrong to me (no orderly/right way/time to call delete),
it's not prohibited by the compiler. Why?

Comment: exactly what is the problem? You can just `delete f_pMyInt` when you wish to.

Comment: Beacause there are new and delete operators in global scope (and the others too), in fact you can overload them too.

Comment: Where did you read that calling a function at global scope is not possible? This is a seriously wrong assumption

Comment: @drhirsch: Like this: `foo();`

Comment: @AssafLevy: You can't do that because you can't have expression statements at namespace scope - `foo();` is an expression statement. You *can* have declarations with initialisers at namespace scope, and the initialiser can be any expression with a suitable type, including a function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why *shouldn't* it be allowed? All you're doing is *initializing* a global variable, which you are perfectly welcome to do, even if the initialization involves a function call:

```
int i = 5 + 6;

double j(std::sin(1.25));

const Foo k = get_my_foo_on(i, 11, true);

std::ostream & os(std::cout << "hello world\n");

int * p(new int);                // fine but very last-century
std::unique_ptr<int> q(new int); // ah, welcome to the real world

int main() { /* ... */ }
```

Of course you'll need to worry about deleting dynamically allocated objects, whether they were allocated at global scope or not... a resource-owning wrapper class such as `unique_ptr` would be the ideal solution.

Comment: The time we live in - people can't bear the responsibility even for making a call and want to be restricted. ;-)

Comment: Well, I thought that main() always gets called first. You live, you ask, you learn :) Thanks.

Comment: @AssafLevy: Quite on the contrary. If you will, `main()` gets called *last*!

Comment: @AssafLevy: Note this is a C++-ism. In C, initializers cannot be function calls.

Comment: @GMan: Thanks, you guessed right that that was part of the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can call functions from global scope, as part of the initialization of global objects. If you couldn't, you couldn't define global variables of types with constructors, because constructors also are functions. However be aware that the initialization order between different translation units is not well defined, so if your function relies on a global variable from another translation unit, you will be in trouble unless you took special precaution.

Comment: I think you mean `you couldn't define _global_ variables` in your second phrase.

Answer (score 2):

C++ allow processing to happen before and after the `main` function, in particular for static objects with constructors & destructors (their constructor have to run before `main`, their destructor after it). And indeed, the execution order is not well defined.

If you are using GCC, see also its [constructor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) function attribute (which may help to give an order).

Comment: To be precise, the execution order *within* one translation unit is indeed well defined (order of declaration); but not across multiple TUs.

Comment: Does that mean that `delete ptr;` after the `main()`'s ending brace will be called after main exits?

Comment: Yes. since in the example above it is called from inside the destructor of `GLOBAL`